# Could not find OpenHelperClass because none of the generic parameters of class

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

I am using the ormlite with sqlite. But we are getting the error are like :

> 07-11 12:39:10.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1415): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   07-11 12:39:10.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1415): Process:
>   com.mmd.testormlite, PID: 1415 07-11 12:39:10.680:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1415): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not
>   find OpenHelperClass because none of the generic parameters of class
>   class com.mmd.testormlite.MainActivity extends
>   OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper.  You should use getHelper(Context, Class)
>   instead. 07-11 12:39:10.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1415):  at
>   com.j256.ormlite.android.apptools.OpenHelperManager.lookupHelperClass(OpenHelperManager.java:273)
>   07-11 12:39:10.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1415):   at
>   com.j256.ormlite.android.apptools.OpenHelperManager.getHelper(OpenHelperManager.java:105)
>   07-11 12:39:10.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1415):   at
>   data.DatabaseManager.getHelper(DatabaseManager.java:17) 07-11
>   12:39:10.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1415):     at
>   data.Repo.(Repo.java:13) 07-11 12:39:10.680:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1415):   at
>   com.mmd.testormlite.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:28) 07-11
>   12:39:10.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1415):     at
>   android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438) 07-11 12:39:10.680:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1415):   at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422) 07-11
>   12:39:10.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1415):     at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 07-11
>   12:39:10.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1415):     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 07-11
>   12:39:10.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1415):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 07-11 12:39:10.680:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1415):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 07-11
>   12:39:10.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1415):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 07-11
>   12:39:10.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1415):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 07-11 12:39:10.680:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1415):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>   07-11 12:39:10.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1415):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 07-11
>   12:39:10.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1415):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

DatabaseManager class :

```
public class DatabaseManager<H extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper> {

    private H helper;

    public H getHelper(Context context)
    {
        if(helper == null)
        {
            helper = (H) OpenHelperManager.getHelper(context);//The method getHelper(Context) from the type OpenHelperManager is deprecated. why ?
        }
        return helper;
    }

    public void releaseHelper(H helper)
    {
        if (helper != null) {
            OpenHelperManager.release();//The method getHelper(Context) from the type OpenHelperManager is deprecated. why ?
            helper = null;
        }
    }

}
```

DatabaseHelper class :

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper{
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "db.sqlite";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private Dao<News, Integer> userDao = null;


    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

        DatabaseInitializer initializer = new DatabaseInitializer(context);
        try {
            initializer.createDatabase();
            initializer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db, ConnectionSource connectionSource) {
        try {
            Log.i(DatabaseHelper.class.getName(), "onCreate");

            TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, News.class);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.e(DatabaseHelper.class.getName(), "Can't create database", e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, ConnectionSource connectionSource, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        try {
            Log.i(DatabaseHelper.class.getName(), "onUpgrade");

            TableUtils.dropTable(connectionSource, News.class, true);

            onCreate(db);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.e(DatabaseHelper.class.getName(), "Can't drop databases", e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        super.close();
        userDao = null;
    }

    public Dao<News, Integer> getNewsDao() {
        if (userDao == null) {
            try {
                userDao =DaoManager.createDao(getConnectionSource(), News.class);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
            return userDao;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the important line in the error:

> E/AndroidRuntime(1415): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find OpenHelperClass because none of the generic parameters of class class com.mmd.testormlite.MainActivity extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper. You should use getHelper(Context, Class) instead.

OrmLite is trying to use the context you passed in (in this case, `MainActivity`) *as the OpenHelperClass*.

From the [ORMLite documentation for `OpenHelperManager.getHelper(Context ctx)`](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-android/com/j256/ormlite/android/apptools/OpenHelperManager.html#getHelper(android.content.Context)):

> Similar to `getHelper(Context, Class)` (which is recommended) except we have to find the helper class through other means. This method requires that the Context be a class that extends one of ORMLite's Android base classes such as `OrmLiteBaseActivity`. Either that or the helper class needs to be set in the strings.xml.

So, you have four options:

- for you to simply pass in your Activity context in order to acquire the Helper class, your Activity has to extend `OrmLiteBaseActivity`.
- you could set the class name in the strings.xml file as [detailed in the docs](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_4.html#Use-With-Android): `<string name="open_helper_classname">your.package.name.DatabaseHelper</string>` or similar
- you could set the class name through a call to [`OpenHelperManager.setOpenHelperClass(Class openHelperClass)`](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-android/com/j256/ormlite/android/apptools/OpenHelperManager.html#setOpenHelperClass(java.lang.Class))
- you could supply a concrete class name in your `DatabaseManager` class, like so: `helper = OpenHelperManager.getHelper(context, DatabaseHelper.class);`

Finally, you ask why `OpenHelperManager.release();` is deprecated. I'm not sure *why* it's deprecated (the docs indicate that this may simply be a naming/convention change), but you should be using `OpenHelperManager.releaseHelper();` instead.